# How can I calculate degree of distortion on an Azimuthal Equidistant projection?

Tags: coordinate-system, reprojection-mathematics

The Tissot's indicatrix of an Azimuthal Equidistant projection shows ellipses being stretched along latitudes.

How can I calculate the degree (amount) of this distortion?  That is, what is the ratio of major axis to minor axis of a Tissot ellipse as a function of latitude (assuming the center of projection is the north pole)?

**Edit:**
Found numerical values on the [GIS help page](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/map-projections/azimuthal-equidistant.htm).

```
Degrees from center     Percentage of scale distortion along parallels
15                      1.2
30                      4.7
45                      11.1
60                      20.9
90                      57
```

I can interpolate this well and get what I need.  But would still be good to know what the analytical formula is.  Feels like a function of `cos(latitude)` since an Azimuthal Equidistant projects latitudes with linearly increasing distance from center instead of cosine.

[image: Azimuthal Equidistant Tissot's indicatrix]

Comment: Is this homework? Anyway, see Snyder's [Map Projections: A Working Manual](https://pubs.er.usgs.gov/publication/pp1395).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the scale distortion from the latitude with this simple formula (latitude in radians) given an origin at the North Pole:

```
(pi/2) - lat
------------
  cos(lat)
```

This will give you the ellipse's ratio you're looking for.

Example with 60°N:

```
(pi/2) - (pi*60/180)
--------------------   = 1.04719...
   cos(pi*60/180)
```

Which is a 4.7% distortion as stated in ArcGIS Help.